# How can I configure Tomcat to accept the root request?

Tags: tomcat

I have a web application that downloads a file, appealing to the server. I want to replace the path *server address* `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/downloads` with the local folder `tomcat/webapps/ROOT/downloads`. How can I configure Tomcat to search for files in this folder?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`<PostResources>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/resources.html#Nested_Components).

This will allow Tomcat to load files from a location which is *outside* the deployed web application. I highly recommend placing your downloaded files outside the web application's deployment directory because otherwise if the application is un-deployed, all your files will be deleted.

Be aware that there are some security implications to using `<PostResources>`: if you are careless, an attacker can upload executable files there and, well, execute them.